# Tabular doesn't center last cell

Tags: tables

I got the following latex code, the last cells aren't centred, but I said that it should center the cells in all columns?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|>{\centering}m{2.5cm}}|}%        
        \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{Fragestellung 1} & \textbf{Fragestellung 2} & \textbf{Fragestellung 3} & \textbf{Fragestellung 4} \\ \tabularnewline \hline
        \textbf{Proband} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert}  &\textbf{Likert Skala Wert}\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        1 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 7\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        4 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 4\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{}  & \textbf{}\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{Durchschnitt:} & \textbf{3,1428} & \textbf{2,2857} & \textbf{3,2857} & \textbf{3}\\  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{Durchschnitt F1- F4:} & \textbf{2,9285} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{}\\  \tabularnewline\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

My table looks like:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: but how can i fix this

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each cell in the last column of your table is terminated by `\\  \tabularnewline`, either of these on their own would trigger a new line of the table. However, as you have both the `\\` gets treated as a `\newline` and so the final column is typeset with text followed by a blank new line.

Removing one (using `\tabularnewline` is better being unambiguous) will vertically center, with most rows becoming single-line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|>{\centering}m{2.5cm}}|}%        
        \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{Fragestellung 1} & \textbf{Fragestellung 2} & \textbf{Fragestellung 3} & \textbf{Fragestellung 4} \tabularnewline \hline
        \textbf{Proband} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert} & \textbf{Likert Skala Wert}  &\textbf{Likert Skala Wert}  \tabularnewline\hline
        1 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 7  \tabularnewline\hline
        2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2  \tabularnewline\hline
        3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2  \tabularnewline\hline
        4 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2  \tabularnewline\hline
        5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2  \tabularnewline\hline
        6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2  \tabularnewline\hline
        7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 4  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{}  & \textbf{}  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{Durchschnitt:} & \textbf{3,1428} & \textbf{2,2857} & \textbf{3,2857} & \textbf{3}  \tabularnewline\hline
        \textbf{Durchschnitt F1- F4:} & \textbf{2,9285} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{}  \tabularnewline\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The empty `\textbf{}` are likely unnecessary, cells can be left blank or set with something fixed height like `\strut`

Comment: There is no guarantee that this table will fit within the width of the textblock.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use the `tabularray` package for your table. This way you can easily adjust the height of the rows, the alignment and much more without having to manually infer with anything.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={XXXXX},
      vlines,
      hlines,
      rows={ht=0.5cm},
      cells={valign=m,halign=c},
      row{1,2,Y,Z}={font=\bfseries}
    }
         & Fragestellung 1 & Fragestellung 2 & Fragestellung 3 & Fragestellung 4 \\  
        Proband & Likert Skala Wert & Likert Skala Wert & Likert Skala Wert  &Likert Skala Wert\\  
        1 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 7\\  
        2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2\\  
        3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\  
        4 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2\\  
        5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2\\  
        6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\  
        7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 4\\  
        & & & & \\
        Durchschnitt: & 3,1428 & 2,2857 & 3,2857 & 3\\         
        Durchschnitt F1- F4: & 2,9285 & & & \\  
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you greatly simplify and streamline the table layout as well as the underlying code. A major advantage of doing so is that it's no longer necessary to resort to `\scriptsize` (which entails a 30% linear font size reduction); staying with the default, i.e., `\normalsize`, is just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Likert-Skala Werte\strut}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l cccc @{}}        
\toprule
Proband & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Fragestellungen} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\midrule
        1 & 7 & 3 & 7 & 7\\ 
        2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2\\ 
        3 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\ 
        4 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2\\ 
        5 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2\\ 
        6 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\ 
        7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 4\\ 
\midrule
Durchschnitt & 3,1428 & 2,2857 & 3,2857 & 3,0000 \\ 
Durchschnitt F1--F4 & 2,9285 &  &  & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```